# Need C# ASP.Net Page To Run Automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, process

I have an ASP.Net page that runs every 30 seconds.  I takes data from a text file and updates a database in SQL Server 2012.  I need this to run all day every day instead of me manually starting up IE and running this page.  Is there a way I can easily make this into an exe or service or some other process that I can run without worry that it won't stop by mistake?

Best Regards,
Andy

Comment: _..it won't stop by mistake_ Mistake by whom exactly? By your code? By your OS? By a person? Task Schedule is good for such a process I think.

Comment: Perhaps you can give windows services a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a windows form application (console) and use the windows Task scheduler to configure the executable to run per your schedule.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Windows Service to run every 30 seconds as a background process.

Take a look at this.  They are actually a lot easier to get up and running than  you might think.

[Develop and Install a Windows Service in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/naresh.avari/develop-and-install-a-windows-service-in-C-Sharp/)